# Using javascript Raphael I lose onhover when setting fill color on a button click

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using Raphael to create some SVG shapes and when I hover over them I set there color to green but when I set the shape color using a button it some how loses the hover state even though I didn't change it. Is there a way to reset it or not overwrite it when I set the color manually?

This is my HTML

```
<style>
    #container path:hover {
        fill:   #556B2F;
    }
</style>

<div id="container"></div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onClick="updateBox()" >Update</button>
        <button type="button" onClick="resetBox()">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code to load the Raphael paths

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var paper = Raphael("container", 500, 150);

        var attr = {
            "fill": "#b9b9b9",
            "stroke": "black",
            "stroke-miterlimit": "4",
            "stroke-width": "2"
        };

        var box1 = paper.path("M50,10 150,10 150,100 50,100 50,10z").attr(attr);
        box1.node.id = "Box1";
        paper.path("M200,10 300,10 300,100 200,100 200,10z").attr(attr);
    };
</script>
```

Finally my functions to set the color of the path manually.

```
<script>
    function updateBox() {
        var county = document.getElementById('Box1');
        county.setAttribute('style', 'fill: red');
    };

    function resetBox() {
        var county = document.getElementById('Box1');
        county.setAttribute('style', 'fill: #b9b9b9');
    };
</script>
```

The last thing I tried was removing the hover from the CSS and assigning the highlight to the .onMouseOver and .onMouseOut but when I assign the new fill color with the button the hover does not work again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function updateBox() {
        var county = document.getElementById('Box1');
        //county.setAttribute('style', 'fill: red');
        county.classList.add('setRed');
    };

    function resetBox() {
        var county = document.getElementById('Box1');
        //county.setAttribute('style', 'fill: #b9b9b9');
        county.classList.add('setGray');
    };
</script>



<style>
    #container path:hover {
        fill:   #556B2F;
    }
    .setRed{
        fill: red;
    }
    .setGray{
        fill: #b9b9b9;
    }
</style>
```

IF you use `setAttribute` and set `background` or `fill`, it will be fixed.

Comment: This only works in chrome and not IE. Plus this only works on the initial load but once the button has been pressed it doesn't work a second time.